# Unable to drag and drop widgets in Qt Designer

Tags: qt

I got a Qt 4 installation using `sudo apt-get install qtcreator`. I am able to get everything to compile using gcc 4.8. However, when it comes to using Qt Designer to edit the UI of a window, Qt Designer fails. Whenever I drag a widget over the window--it doesn't matter which widget--the cursor changes to a circle with a slash through it. Interestingly enough the only widget I can add is the horizontal line separator. I'm not sure why I am unable to add widgets to the window using Qt Designer.

EDIT: I just realized that it is worth noting that I am working on the pi remotely through a direct ethernet connection. I found that dragging and dropping works in Qt Designer when run through ssh X11. However when I run Qt Designer from the desktop view through tightvncviewer, dragging and dropping doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to point me in the right direction. It obviously depends on the vnc server somehow.

[drag n drop doesnt work with tightvnc](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1497635)

[no drag n drop with qt 4.7](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-34478)